# Why Uncaught nc error appear at geocomplete bind function

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map with a input box to search location.  When I load the page I am getting the error at the console shown in image below. I checked and found out that the that error is coming from geocomplete().bind function. These are the codes I have tried. Can anybody help me why I am getting that error.

```
<div class="box-search">
    <input id="geocomplete" type="text" class="inputtxt-style -search" placeholder="Search Location">
</div>    
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=1&amp;libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=1&amp;libraries=places&callback=initialize"
async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function initialize()
    {
        //google map and marker code

        $("#geocomplete")
        .geocomplete()
        .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
        var searchLocation = result.geometry.location;
        var searchLatitude = searchLocation.lat();
        var searchLon = searchLocation.lng();
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(searchLatitude),parseFloat(searchLon));
        mapSingle.panTo(myLatlng);
        });
    }
</script>
```

[image: Error at console]

Comment: Where is your script tags?

Comment: @Thili77 you mean googleapis? yes its there

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error (with an emphasis on **complete**)

Comment: Why do you load Maps JavaScript API twice?